# Websocket dependency runtime error, could not find an implementation class

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, tyrus

I'm faced with an interesting problem. I have an intellij plugin which creates an intellij tool window which, as part of its functionality, uses a websocket. In my build.gradle, I have `compile group: 'org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles', name: 'tyrus-standalone-client', version: '1.15'`. When I run my java code as an application and trigger the methods programmatically, or using JFrame guis, the websocket runs as it should. However, when using the same compile line in my plugin tool window, I get the following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find an 
implementation class.
at ElasticsearchClientEndpoint.<init>(ElasticsearchClientEndpoint.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find an implementation class.
at javax.websocket.ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer(ContainerProvider.java:73)
at ElasticsearchClientEndpoint.<init>(ElasticsearchClientEndpoint.java:16)
```

I've tried running the plugin from a project which has the same dependency but I still get this error. I can't work out why I'm getting this error, any help would be excellent.